# Compiling code for raw assembly code injection using GCC

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-optimization, powerpc

I want to compile some `C` or `C++` code directly to `PowerPC` assembly without any generated helper functions, standard libraries, `ELF` headers and so on. This is similar to what the [`compiler explorer`](https://godbolt.org) does but I'm still having some trouble with it.

Let's say I want to compile the following code directly to raw assembly, only generating a single function and inlining everything:

```
auto get_address() {
    const auto value = *(int *) 0x1234; // Read the value from address 0x1234
    return reinterpret_cast<int *>(value); // Return it as address
}

void perform_write() {
    const auto address = get_address(); // Get the address using the helper function
    *address = 1; // Assign a value to the address
}
```

The entry point should be `perform_write()` obviously. My expected output is something like the following:

```
li r9,4660
li r10,1
lwz r9,0(r9)
stw r10,0(r9)
blr
```

Now, if I use the compiler explorer website, [I almost get what I want](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/VMMxyw):

[image]

This has the following issues:

1. The helper function `get_address()` is generated despite the fact that it is inlined in `perform_write()`. How can I get `GCC` to omit the redundant `get_address()` from the output? Can I mark the `perform_write()` as entry point somehow to accomplish this? I tried using the attribute `__attribute__((always_inline))` but it did nothing (probably since `GCC` already inlines the code by default but does not remove the unused function)
2. Unimportant: Replacing the `%` signs would be nice even though it does not matter for further compilation to machine code. The `Intel` checkbox is disabled and `%` is usually `AT&T` syntax.

I want to accomplish these things preferably with compiler flags or by modifying the source code if necessary. I want to avoid post-processing the output with a programming language to get the desired output since that certainly works but might be less robust.

Comment: 1. mark your `get_address` function `static`. 2. intel vs at&t only applies to x86. You can of course use `-mno-regnames` but since you added `-mregnames` explicitly I guess you don't want that.

Comment: If you don't mark a function `static` is has global scope. The compiler **has to** generate it because other units may call it.

Comment: @Jester: Yep, that did the trick, thanks :)